# Boolean uniform in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

How can I pass `bool` value to shader via OpenTK?
I have not seen such overload for Uniform1. How my purposes I use float variable and than check something like

```
if (floatValue > 0.5) {}
```

But it doesn't looks like nice way to do things. Any ideas with `bool` uniform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `glUniform1i()` or `glUniform1f()` to set a `bool` uniform. For both of these, the uniform value will be set to `FALSE` if you pass zero, and `TRUE` otherwise. So to set the uniform to `FALSE`, use either one of these two:

```
glUniform1i(0);
gUniform1f(0.0f);
```

To set it to `TRUE`, use either one of these:

```
glUniform1i(1);
gUniform1f(1.0f);
```

Any other non-zero value instead of `1` or `1.0f` would be legal as well. I would personally prefer the integer version with values `0` and `1`, since the `int` type is more closely related to `bool`.

The spec language defining this behavior is (copied from section 2.11.4 of OpenGL 3.3 spec):

> When loading values for a uniform declared as a boolean, a boolean vector, an array of booleans, or an array of boolean vectors, the Uniform*i{v}, Uniform*ui{v}, and Uniform*f{v} set of commands can be used to load boolean values. Type conversion is done by the GL. The uniform is set to FALSE if the input value is 0 or 0.0f, and set to TRUE otherwise.